# DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged is not working

Tags: c#

Selecting Value From DropDownList , But it does't call for SelectedIndexChanged Event.

for selecting value it must be call for SelectedIndexchanged event where my code is , but I did'nt go for SelectedIndexChanged Event when i try to Select Something From DropDownList

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindContrydropdown();
    }
}

protected void BindContrydropdown()
{
    // Connection path for database

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TblCountry", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddlCountry.DataSource = ds;
    ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryID";
    ddlCountry.DataBind();
    ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    ddlState.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}

protected void ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue);

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TblState where CountryID=" + CountryID, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    ddlState.DataSource = ds;
    ddlState.DataTextField = "StateName";
    ddlState.DataValueField = "StateID";
    ddlState.DataBind();
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td>Select Country:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry"
                          runat="server"
                          AutoPostBack="True"
                          OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Select City:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server">

        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean with _not working_. Do you get error messages? The code is not called? The results are not what you expect to be?

Comment: yes , When i click on drop down its index not changed . i put debugger also but selectedindexed changed not called

Comment: And if you put a breakpoint in the BindContrydropdown is it called? Do you have this DDL filled with all the country names available in your db?

Comment: yes its called and i have all the country names listed in dropdownlist

Comment: Try adding the event in on page_load. Add ddlCountry.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged); above your check if it's a postback.

Comment: No its not working

Comment: Can you update your question with exactly how you tried this in your code? Also, by "not working" do you mean that it's still not getting called?

Comment: yes its not getting called . selectedindexed changed not called when i click on dropdownlist

Comment: Are you using asp.net webforms? Is your drop down list contained within form tags?

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is cutting the code within the SelectedIndexChanged event, deleting the event, double clicking the drop down list to recreate the event and posting your code back in.

Comment: I already did it @sr28

Comment: And it's within form tags?

Comment: yes its in from tag @sr28

Comment: The code as written should work. There is something else in play here, something that we can't see. If it is possible I suggest to post the whole ASPX page and the relative CS.

Comment: Is it within an update panel or something? As @Steve suggests, could you paste the whole aspx page?